# Rotating a SVG with Css (Animation)

Tags: css, html, vector, svg

I want to have a css-coded animated rotating svg image. I have no idea how to do that. At the end it has to look exactly like this: http://baveltje.com/logo/logo.html. I am completely new to css. The rotating svg's are gear1.svg and gear2.svg. I want them to rotate 360 degres for infinite time and I want to call them <.div class="gear1"> and gear2.. Is it possible to let it look exactly like the logo does in the link, but rotating?

I tried to use [jsfiddle.net/gaby/9Ryvs/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9Ryvs/7/), but with no results. It has to go the same speed like that fiddle does!

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
div {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f00;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is your original animation css (I have removed prefixes to keep it simple):

```
#gear{
    animation-name: ckw;
    animation-duration: 15.5s;
}
@keyframes ckw {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

In ***#gear*** you should add:

- ***animation-iteration-count*** to ***infinite*** to keep it rolling
- ***transform-origin*** to center of your div ***50% 50%*** to get gear rolling around itself
- ***display*** to ***inline-block***

Result:

```
#gear{
    animation-name: ckw;
    animation-duration: 15.5s;
    /* Things added */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    /* <--- */
}
@keyframes ckw {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

And of course add correct prefixes.

Comment: thanks, 
if anyone tries to create a simple spinning object use this line :
` animation: <KEYFRAME_NAME> 1s linear infinite`